# Does Telnet need to be activated on both devices I am using or not?

Tags: networking, troubleshooting

I've searched everywhere for the answer to this question but can't find a simple yes or no.

Basically, I have a virtual server hosting some services and then a physical panel PC in another part of the building. The services usually connect over TCP (Port 7776) but on this occasion are unable despite being able to ping successfully etc. I've checked for policies that could block the connection as well as the user permissions for the service to ensure it has high enough permission levels to do all it needs to and am assured by the person who set up the server all up (not us) that there are no blocking points in the network like managed switches, firewalls or in the VM setup itself.

However, I want install telnet on the Panel PC and just test the ports we need directly to give a simple yes or no as to whether we are blocked or not somewhere (should've been done as Step 1 really but we we weren't involved at this level)

My question, do I also need to ask the owner of the Virtual Server to activate telnet there too or I can proceed without them? - I have access to the Panel PC but not the server.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about protocols above OSI layer-4 are off-topic here, as are questions about hosts/servers. You could try to ask this question on [sf] for a business network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to access the virtual server, and this is not your equipment... you need to involve the other vendor. Gaining access to this equipment and not involving them is digital trespassing and can have legal action.

If you do have permission to  telnet from the Panel PC into the Virtual server, then yes. You will need a telnet client on the Panel PC and a telnet server on the Virtual server.

Comment: It's a virtual server we allowed access to so no problem for trying to access etc. The second part of your answer was perfect though and just what I needed. Thanks!